# Execute a plugin only on post pages

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development

I am building a plugin that is only useful and should only run on pages where posts are featured.

Is there a way to only run the plugin on pages that display posts?

Comment: there are several ways to limit where/when a plugin does various things, depending on what exactly your plugin does- loading of styles, loading of scripts, modification of queries, etc., you'll have to provide more details as to what your plugin does for an actual, practical answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, the plugin is loaded long before WordPress has figured out if it should display a single post.

But you can restrict the code of the plugin to do something only then.

Example:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if ( ! is_single() )
        return;

    // initialize plugin code here.
});
```